# Bijective continuous map from subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ to a manifold of dimension $n$

Tags: smooth-manifolds, manifolds, topological-manifolds

I'd like to know if the following assertion is true or not (if true I'd like an example):

There exists a positive integer $n$, and a manifold $M$ of dimension $n$ such that there is no subset $X \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ and a map $f: X \rightarrow M$ that is bijective and continuous (note that $f^{-1}$ does not have to be continuous).

I know that there are some manifolds for which this does not work: take the polar angle parameterization of the circle $f: [0, 2\pi) \rightarrow S^1$, which is a continuous bijection.

Comment: In order to avoid triviality, you need to assume that M is separable.

Comment: And there is no such separable M.

Comment: Conclusion: this Q. is too easy for MO.

Comment: @WlodAA how does one construct such a map?

Comment: Use the separability assumption about M. It's straightforward. (Perhaps someone else will be willing to provide the rest).

Comment: Pick a countable atlas, embed all the domains as disjoint open balls, then restrict the i-th map to the preimage of all points that are not hit by the previous charts.